# Imask replaces Y with 2 when the from is from 2000

Tags: javascript, angular, imaskjs

I am trying to mask `MM/DD/YYYY` format for calendar using `angular-imask`.
When I have the from as 2024 instead of displaying `MM/DD/YYYY` as placeholder it is displaying `MM/DD/2YYY`. Is there a way to always display `MM/DD/YYYY` irrespective of what is passed in from?

```
{
      mask: pattern,
      lazy: false,
      blocks: {
        YY: {
          mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
          placeholderChar: 'Y',
          from: 24,
          to: 99
        },

        YYYY: {
          mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
          placeholderChar: 'Y',
          from: 2024,
          to: 2100
        },

        DD: {
          mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
          placeholderChar: 'D',
          from: 1,
          to: 31
        },

        MM: {
          mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
          placeholderChar: 'M',
          from: 1,
          to: 12
        },
      }
    };
```

[image: Masked date format when I pass the from as 2024]